# checking if a set of objects is present in an array a number of times RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to check if a set of objects which I turn with a .each method are present in an array a given number of times? DOes anyone know if it is possible?
I hope I've been clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question:

Given two arrays:

```
a1 = [1,1,2,3,3,4,5]
a2 = [1,3,5]
```

You can check how many times each element of the second array appears in the first in a few different ways. Here's one:

```
items_present = true
a2.each do |thing|
  if a1.select{|x| x == thing }.size < 2
    items_present = false
    break
  end
end
```

`items_present` will be true if each thing appears at least two times.

Comment: thank you! that seems to work, I have to do the same now with date formats. And when I try to do it it says in the navigator "undefined method each for date format

Comment: @user2614075 sounds like you're calling `.each` on something that's not an array.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand what you're asking, this might be what you want:

```
list = ["a","b","b","c","c","c"]
array = ["a","b","c"]
```

Suppose you have these arrays above, running the following would give you a hash "*number*" with the number of times that an element inside "*array*" is present inside "*list*"

```
number = {}
array.each do |key|
    number[key] = list.select{|item| item == key}.size
end
```

This way, number[array.first] gives you 1. That's because "a" (array.first) is present 1 time inside *list*. number["c"] would give you 3.